# Percentage of values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I would like to obtain the percentage of values in a nested dictionary of the form:

```
{'first': OrderedDict([('Jan', 2), ('Feb', 1)]), 'second': OrderedDict([('Jan', 3), ('Feb', 5)])}
```

The expected result should be like:

```
{'first': OrderedDict([('Jan', 40%), ('Feb', 16.6%)]), 'second': OrderedDict([('Jan', 60%), ('Feb', 83.3%)])}
```

The above result should be obtained as percentage: for the dictionary with key 'first':

```
Jan : 2/5 *100 = 40%
Feb: 1/6 *100 = 16.6%
```

For the dictionary with key 'second':

```
Jan : 3/5 *100 = 60%
Feb: 5/6 *100 = 83.3%
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer is pretty good, but if you want to get the total values for all months you can try for loop two times , First to sum all values and second to update changes, like :

```
x={'first': OrderedDict([('Jan', 2), ('Feb', 1)]), 'second': OrderedDict([('Jan', 3), ('Feb', 5)])}

total = [0]*2
for k in x :
    for idx, month in enumerate(x[k]):
        total[idx] += x[k][month]

for k, v in x.items():
    for idx, month in enumerate(v) : 
        v.update({month:round((v[month]/total[idx])*100,2)})

print(x)
```

This will generate output as :

```
{'first': OrderedDict([('Jan', 40.0), ('Feb', 16.67)]),
 'second': OrderedDict([('Jan', 60.0), ('Feb', 83.33)])}
```

Comment: Hi @Somitra Gupta thank you for this. What if i want to obtain the sum for each months, with an expected output as:  {'sum_of_the_two': OrderedDict([('Jan', 5), ('Feb', 6)])}

Comment: make a orderdict with null values such as `new = OrderedDict({month:0 for k in x for month in x[k]})` 
`for k in x : 
    for month in x[k]:
        new[month] += x[k][month]`

Answer (score 0):

Ordered Dictionary in python follows some of the traits as a normal dictionary you can update the value using .update('k': 'v')

`for k, v in d.items(): v.update({'Jan': (v['Jan']/5)*100}) v.update({'Feb': (v['Feb']/6)*100})`